# How to split a string from a specified place

Tags: android, string

I want to make a form in my android app with a field to enter name(not first name and last name). After getting the name, I want to split it into first name and last name. For example:

> I got **Jack Dawson** as name.

Now I want to split it from the place where it contains space. i.e.

- First name : **Jack**
- Last name : **Dawson**

Comment: `.split(" ")` should do the job, what did you try? (see https://ideone.com/NunxeR)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say for example the string is "Jack Dawson".
Now, if you want to split it with spaces,

```
String currentString = "Jack Dawson";
String[] separated = currentString.split(" ");
```

This way, you will get an array of string where, `seperated[0] = "Jack"` and `seperated[1] = "Dawson"`.
I hope it solves your problem.